# How to custom format an String in Vba.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem when trying to format an ID in Visual Basic.
An example of the format I need is this: 00-0000-00000
Example of the value on the screen would be: 01-0053-00404
Please, if someone could help me, I would be grateful.

Comment: Hello! There is no VBA.NET. Either vba or VB.NET. Since you tag visual-studio, it's probably the second one

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?  ...or is this in VBA, like with Excel or Access?

Comment: Sorry im using visual studio, programming with visual basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve the problem, I just had to separate the String to format it and add it to it.
To those who responded thank you very much for trying to help and it was my mistake for not specifying which platform I was using.

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.Handled = True
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
        Dim stringlist As String = cedula.Text.ToString()
        Dim arrayList() As String = stringlist.Split("-")
        Dim i As Integer

        Dim union() As String = {arrayList(0).PadLeft(2, "0"), arrayList(1).PadLeft(4, "0"), arrayList(2).PadLeft(5, "0")}

        cedula.Text = Join(union, "-")
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question tags were unclear as to which platform you're using but I will assume VBA and provide a quick answer.

It's an easy fix, especially since you have the [custom number format](https://support.office.com/article/create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4) with your question.

In order to apply it, you just need to place the desired format in the `Type` field of the `Custom` option in the `Format Cells` dialog.

[image]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> is a shortcut to open the `Format Cells` dialog.

Comment: I need that in visual basic language, im using visual studio.